# divisibility of the convolution of the coprimes of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the coprimes of n $c_0$$<$$c_1$$<$...<$c_{2*m}$ find the sum S=sum from k=0 to k=2*m of (c_0)*c_(2*m-k).  S mod n=r and (n-r)|S.  If this is true, why?

Comment: I spent 20 minutes trying to follow you procedure of proper entry and had

Comment: and had little luck.